# Multithreading in Python. Running two functions at once

Tags: python, multithreading

So I have one function that extracts images from videos I have in a folder and another that writes those images into another folder. These functions execute one after the other and I was wondering if I could save time by having them run together. Essentially, I have to wait while the images are saved to start extracting the next batch of images, but I want to run them simultaneously such that while the images are being saved the next batch is already being extracted. What's the best way to do this in Python? I'm using a neural network running on my GPU to extract the images.

Comment: Take a look at the ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor classes from concurrent.futures

Comment: you're unlikely to get any speedup from multithreading in computation-heavy functions because of [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). This can be overcome by multiprocessing, at the cost of interprocess communication overhead - which in this case might be quite high. Unless the second function has a severe I/O bottleneck, I'd assume in this particular situation it's not worth it

Comment: Generally, APIs that use GPU release GIL. So, if GPU is your bottleneck, it could be improved enough even with multi-threading. For multi-processing, it is a good idea to use [shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) to minimize overhead. Either way, what is best for you depends on your requirements, and there is no silver bullet.